# How to run the HTML5 video in webview in android

Tags: android, html5-video, android-websettings

From last one week i try to find how to play a html5 video in android webview i read so many blog and questions in the stack overflow but my problem is solve.i am using `.mp4 , .wevm ,ogv and also .3gp` format but noon of format is running.
i run  these videos in the two different device one is `micro-max funbook` with `android 4.0` and the another device is a `Samsung device` with `2.3.3 android os`.

this is my code.

```
  url="file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/unzipped/HTML5/res/test1.html";


    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         view.loadUrl(url);
         return true;
       }    
           });

   webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

For API level 11+ it should suffice that you add the attribute `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to the `<application>` tag in your Android manifest file.

For older APIs you need to implement the methods `onShowCustomView` and `onHideCustomView` in your your own `WebChromeClient`.

Or you can check out the [html5webview](http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/)